# How to view two different objects in the same primefaces datatable?

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have to view two different objects in the same datatable.
Is that possible? How can i do it? 
I'm using primefaces 3.5.
Thanks for your help.

```
 <p:dataTable  id="lesClients" var="Client" value="#{listerClientsBean.listeclients}" rowKey="#{Client.idclient}"  
                                              selection="#{listerClientsBean.selectedClient}" selectionMode="single"  emptyMessage="Aucune Information dans la base de données" 

                                              paginator="true" rows="12"  
                                              paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                                              rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">

                                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" process="@this"  />

                                    <f:facet name="header">  
                                        <p:outputPanel>  
                                            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />  
                                            <p:inputText id="globalFilter"  style="width:150px" />  
                                        </p:outputPanel>  
                                    </f:facet> 

                                    <f:facet name="header">  
                                        Afficher les Clients
                                    </f:facet>  
                                    <p:column headerText="Num carte" filterBy="#{Client.codeabar}"
                                              sortBy="#{Client.codeabar}">
                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="Num carte" />
                                        </f:facet>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{Client.codeabar}" />
                                    </p:column>


                                    <p:column headerText="Nom" filterBy="#{Client.nom}"
                                              sortBy="#{Client.nom}">
                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="Nom" />
                                        </f:facet>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{Client.nom}" />
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column headerText="Prenom" filterBy="#{Client.prenom}"
                                              sortBy="#{Client.prenom}">
                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="Prenom" />
                                        </f:facet>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{Client.prenom}" />
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column headerText="Email" filterBy="#{Client.email}"
                                              sortBy="#{Client.email}">
                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="Email" />
                                        </f:facet>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{Client.email}" />
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column headerText="Login" filterBy="#{Client.login}"
                                              sortBy="#{Client.login}">
                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="Login" />
                                        </f:facet>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{Client.login}" />
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column headerText="date naiss" filterBy="#{Client.datnaiss}"
                                              sortBy="#{Client.datnaiss}">
                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="Date naiss" />
                                        </f:facet>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{Client.datnaiss}" />
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column headerText="tel" filterBy="#{Client.tel}"
                                              sortBy="#{Client.tel}">
                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="tel" />
                                        </f:facet>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{Client.tel}" />
                                    </p:column>


                                    <p:column>  
                                        <p:commandButton style="margin-right:10%" id="affichButton" 
                                                         icon="ui-icon-search" 
                                                         update=":j_idt9:displayClients"
                                                         oncomplete="ClientDialog.show()" />

                                    </p:column>


                                    <f:facet name="footer">  

                                        <p:commandButton style="margin-right:10%" id="EditButton" 
                                                         value="Modifier"  icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                                                         oncomplete="ClientDialogEdit.show()"
                                                         update=":j_idt9:displayClientsEdit"
                                                          />
                                        <p:commandButton style="margin-right:10%" id="RemoveButton" 
                                                         value="Supprimer"  icon=" ui-icon-trash"
                                                         />
                                    </f:facet> 
                                </p:dataTable>
```

I should add a column in the datatable like this:

```
 <p:column headerText="solde" filterBy="#{Carte.solde}"
                                              sortBy="#{Carte.solde}">
                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="solde" />
                                        </f:facet>
                                         <h:outputText value="#{Carte.solde}" />
                                    </p:column>
```

The solde attribute should be derived from another object "Carte" (not from Client oject)
Is this possible? How can i do this?
Thanks a lot for you help..

Comment: What is the relationship between Carte and Client?

Comment: A "Client" can have 1 or n "Carte"